# Ejecutar una función cuyo nombre se pasa como argumento de otra función que contiene una petición Ajax con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

En una petición Ajax con JQuery necesito colocar en la propiedad **sucess** la ejecución de una función. Pero esta función está pasada como argumento a la función en la que se realiza la petición Ajax. Es decir, dentro de la petición Ajax solo puedo indicar la ejecución de esa función  mediante el parámetro *string* que corresponde a su nombre. El problema que tengo es que si pongo el nombre del parámetro seguido de "();" no se ejecuta como función. De esta forma:

```
success: function (devolucion) {
        callback();          
    },
```

*callback* es el nombre del parámetro que se recibe en la función en la que se realiza la petición. Como mi deseo es que se ejecute esa función escribo el nombre del parámetro añadiendo "**();**", lo cual seguro que no está bien. Necesitaría saber como tendría que escribir ese nombre de función mediante el parámetro que lo contiene para que se pueda ejecutar. Igualmente es algo que no se puede hacer, pero lanzo la consulta porque a veces sí hay soluciones para todo.

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success` de Ajax se autoinvocará al terminar la petición, ejecutará la función que tu le asignes, pero `callback()` está fuera de su scope.
Asigna tu función SIN invocarla. Tu función de callback, en caso de necesitarla, almacenará el resultado de la petición.

Te dejo un ejemplo

```js
$(  () => {

  const cb = (data) => console.log('HOLA MUNDO AQUI', data);
  
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: cb
      });
  });
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto Alberto! Ha quedado muy claro con tu ejemplo. Gracias por tu respuesta.